# Why am I getting a "connection timeout" when adding a node to a Galera cluster?

Tags: mariadb, galera

I am setting up a MariaDB 10.6.11 Galera cluster with two nodes. One node is working and showing as a primary, but when I add the 2nd node I'm getting a "Connection timed out" error :

```
2022-11-29 15:14:35 0 [Warning] WSREP: no nodes coming from prim view, prim not possible 
2022-11-29 15:14:35 0 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(NON_PRIM,61b49a4d-bae4,1) memb { 61b49a4d-bae4,0 } joined { } left { } partitioned { })
2022-11-29 15:14:36 0 [Warning] WSREP: last inactive check more than PT1.5S ago (PT3.50346S), skipping check 
2022-11-29 15:15:05 0 [Note] WSREP: PC protocol downgrade 1 -> 0
2022-11-29 15:15:05 0 [Note] WSREP: view((empty)) 
2022-11-29 15:15:05 0 [ERROR] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110: failed to reach primary view: 110 (Connection timed out) at /home/buildbot/buildbot/build/gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():160 
2022-11-29 15:15:05 0 [ERROR] WSREP: /home/buildbot/buildbot/build/gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():222: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
2022-11-29 15:15:05 0 [ERROR] WSREP: /home/buildbot/buildbot/build/gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1670: Failed to open channel 'ABIS' at 'gcomm://10.77.77.97,10.77.77.124': -110 (Connection timed out) 
2022-11-29 15:15:05 0 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out 
2022-11-29 15:15:05 0 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://10.77.77.97,10.77.77.124) failed: 7 
2022-11-29 15:15:05 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

`server.cnf` file on the 2nd node:

```
binlog_format=ROW
log-bin=mysql-bin
expire_logs_days = 7
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
##innodb_log_file_size=200M
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera-4/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://server ip,server ip"
wsrep_cluster_name='ABIS'
wsrep_node_address='server ip'
wsrep_node_name='hostname'
#wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=root:root123
##tmpdir = /var/lib/tmp
innodb_rollback_on_timeout=1
wsrep_on=ON
max_connections=2000
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.log
wsrep_node_incoming_address=server ip
```

On the 1st node I started it with `Galera_new_cluster` and on the 2nd node I'm trying to start using `systemctl start mariadb`.

What can be wrong with my cluster?

Comment: How did you verify that the connection is possible from the second node to the first one on the specified address and port?